# Tag detail page with Django-taggit

Tags: python, django, django-taggit

Im trying to create pages for tags on my django blog. I already have a simple index page which displays a list of all used tags, now I want to have individual pages for each tag and on that page I will display all posts marked with that tag. The url structure for these tag detail pages will be like this

localhost/tag/my-tag-here

I already have django-taggit installed and added some tags and I have them displaying fine on post detail pages and the tag index page mentioned above but Im getting a 404 when I try to visit each tag detail page such as /tag/test.

These are my files and the full error message below.

views.py

```
def tag_detail(request, tag):


    tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, tag=tag.name)


    return render(request, 'blog/tags_detail.html', {'tag': tag})
```

urls.py (app)

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.blog_index, name='blog_index'),
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/'\
        r'(?P<post>[-\w]+)/$',
        views.blog_post_detail,
        name='blog_post_detail'),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.contact_form, name='contact_form'),
    url(r'^thanks/$', views.thanks_view, name='thanks_view' ),
    url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^upload/$', views.upload_image, name='upload_image'),
    url(r'^tag/(?P<tag>[-/w]+)/$', views.tag_detail, name='tag_detail'),
    url(r'^tags/$', views.tags_index, name='tags_index')

]
```

and this is the full error message

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/tag/test
```

is the problem here in my view or the url structure? For the view I'm not 100% sure if thats the correct way to do it but Ive tried to do it the same as my post detail view.

thanks

Comment: What if `tag.name` for `get_object_or_404` is returning a `404`?

Comment: I have a tag called 'test' in admin though, this tag has been added to some posts and it displays below those posts just fine, I have also used 'tag.name' in my tags_index page which displays all tags and no problems with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your views.py file.
In this code:

```
def tag_detail(request, tag):

    tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, tag=tag.name)

    return render(request, 'blog/tags_detail.html', {'tag': tag})
```

Here you wrote :

```
 tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, tag=tag.name)
```

you passed a tag in URL so correct method would be :

```
 tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, tag=tag)
```

But this will work only if, in your model,you have returned name of the tag as Unicode,Like this:

```
  class Tag(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField()

  def __unicode__(self):
      return unicode(self.name)
```

And if this still does not work then there might be a problem in TEPLATE_DIR setting in settings.py file. Then you have to share settings.py code for project file structure.