# Django tag detail page with taggit

Tags: python, django, django-taggit

I've a very similar problem like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40371598/tag-detail-page-with-django-taggit#_=_). Long story short, I've got a django blog, and for tags I'm using django-taggit which is working nice on the admin page.

[AdminScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJ8wS.jpg)

My main problem is that if I like to filter to a tag by an url address I still receive a 404 error although I red the documentation and couple of stackoverflow post:

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request
>   URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8080/tag/sample/

views.py

```
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from taggit.models import Tag


def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})


def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})


def tag_detail(request, tag):
    tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, tag=tag)
    return render(request, 'blog/tag_detail.html', {'tag': tag})
```

urls.py(app)

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    url(r'^tag/(?P<tag>[-/w]+)/$', views.tag_detail, name='tag_detail'),
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)

    tags = TaggableManager()

    def ttags(self):
        return [t.name for t in self.tags.all()]

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I'm surely know that I miss something (maybe something simple) just can't figure it out what it is. How can I fix this issue?
Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: Okay, I strongly doubted that anyone gonna react to that, but I'm able to avoid 404 with this one in the views.py
[link]https://pastebin.com/2V6Y6PQX
The next problem is that it didn't show the blog posts, so I can only validating the url's.
I changed the regex in the urls.py to this:
https://pastebin.com/XC9X5Pxh.
If anyone helps thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to fix the taggit tagging issue, although it's more like a look than  document or other based solution.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)

    tags = TaggableManager()

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

ursl.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    url(r'^tag/(?P<tag>\w+)/$', views.tag_detail, name='tag_detail'),
]
```

It's pretty self-explanatory until then.

views.py

```
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404


def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})


def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})


def tag_detail(request, tag):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(tags__slug=tag)
    return render(request, 'blog/tag_detail.html', {"posts": posts, "tag": tag})
```

So in the tag_detail def I'm using filtering `tags__slug=tag`. My only main issue about this (although it's working perfectly) than I found this solution by plain luck, I didn't find anything about in the django documentation [field lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#id4) section nor in the [taggit documentation](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=field).

Before I forget the html file of the tag result page:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h2>Posts tagged: {{tag}}</h2>
{% for post in posts %}
<p>{{ post.published_date }}: <a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

If anyone has idea why and how is this working please, let me know.